# AngularJS : Destroying child directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my application i've created two directives, one parentDirective and childDirective.The parent directive dynamically creates child directives depending on some criteria defined in parent on button click of parent directive.

It's working fine but the issue is as I'm changing criteria and recreating child directives the scope of previous child directives are not getting destroyed (Batarang is still showing the old child directive scopes).

I'm using isolated scope for both parent and child directives.

Is there a way to destroy child directives scope from parent. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where I was doing wrong, my code was deleting child directives before destroying it's scope. It's working when i deleted the scope before removing the directive